# docker networking: How to know which ip will be assigned?

Tags: docker

Trying to get acquainted with docker, so bear with me...

If I create a database container (psql) with port 5432 exposed, and then create another webapp which wants to connect on 5432, they get assigned some ip addresses on the bridge network from docker...

probably `172.0.0.1` and `172.0.0.2` respectively. if I fire up the containers, inspect their `ip`s with `docker network inspect <bridge id>`

if I then take those ips and plug in the port on my webapp settings, everything works great...

BUT I shouldn't have to run my webapp, shell into it, change settings, and then run a server, I should be able to just run the container...

So what am I missing here, is there a way to have these two containers networked without having to do all of that?

Comment: I had played with that a little bit (didn't get it to work) but then I noticed the docs said it was deprecated (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) so I thought there must be another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a Docker network

```
docker create network myapp
docker run --network myapp --name db [first-container...]
docker run --network myapp --name webapp [second-container...]
# ... and so on
```

Now you can refer to containers by their names, from within other containers. Just like they were hostnames in DNS.

In the application running in the `webapp` container, you can configure the database server using `db` as if it is a hostname.